# java config blocks - configuring properties in blocks

Tags: java

I want to have a configuration to be specified in blocks. For eg:

```
[Production]
Key = Value

[Development]
Key = Value

[Staging]
Key = Value
```

Then I want to read config as appropriate at run-time.

I can do this in Python. How can I do this in "java"? Is there a java class for it?

Comment: Why negative vote...tell me I will fix the problem statement. Its a clear problem....no ????...I need a solution...I will rewrite...tell me whats missing

Comment: Yes you can do it with all the programming languages in the world if you just write te proper code for it.

Comment: Use the `Properties` class. See javadocs http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html

Comment: You're missing your code.

Answer (score 1):

If the question is whether this is supported by the Java Properties file format, the answer is no. You can hack something up using your own logic and property name conventions, e.g.

```
Production.Key = Value
Development.Key = Value
Staging.Key = Value
```

and then post-process the property map to look up properties in the appropriate scope.

If you're looking to support a specific file format, then it depends on the format. For example, here is a library that supports .ini files, which have the feature you want. http://ini4j.sourceforge.net/

If you're asking if it's possible to implement your own custom parser for your own custom config file format, the answer is Yes.